# Why C++ is NO Copy or Assign for IO Objects?

Tags: c++, io, iostream, istream, ostream

In C++ primer 4th 8.8.1 sections:

Why there is NO Copy or Assign for IO Objects?

```
ofstream out1, out2;  
out1 = out2;              // error: cannot assign stream objects  
ofstream print(ofstream); // error: can't initialize the ofstream parameter  
out2 = print(out2);       // error: cannot copy stream objects
```

Can anyone tell me the reason? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is : it doesnt make sense to copy or reassign a C++ stream.
The real question is: what are you trying to achieve exactly ?